# Odds or Odds Ratio terminology?

Tags: logistic, terminology, odds-ratio, odds

I am having a bit of a tough time with some logistic regression terminology.  I have performed a multivariable logistic regression analysis where I have regressed a binary variable (death, where 1 = dead and 0 = alive) on some covariates, one of which is age (measured in years).  I am then looking at what happens to the outcome when I increase age by 10 years,  holding all else constant.

The resulting model gives me some parameter estimates.  The one for age is $\hat{\beta}_{age}=-0.015$.  So I multiply this parameter by 10 (years) and exponentiate the result getting $exp(10*-0.015)=0.86$.  So, I'm a bit confused as to how to report this.  Which of the following is correct?

1. A 10 year increase in age is associated with a multiplicative $(1-0.86)*100% = 13.92$% decrease in the **odds** of death, holding all over variables constant; or
2. **The odds ratio** is decreased a multiplicative $(1-0.86)*100% = 13.92$% for each 10 year increase in age, holding all other variables constant?

Essentially, I'm confused over whether the result is a 13.92% decrease in the **odds** or **odds ratio**?  Can you help me clarify.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be reported as:

> The odds of death are reduced by 14% with every 10 year increase in
>   age, i.e. the odds ratio was 0.86, after controlling for other 
>   factors.

or:

> After controlling for other factors, the odds ratio for 10 year 
>   increase in age was 0.86, i.e. the odds of
>   death were reduced by 14% with every 10 year increase in age.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is very helpful, @rnso.  I really appreciate it.  I knew I was missing something subtle here, but just needed someone to clarify for me.  Many thanks!